# Check for microphone permissions on safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I see that permissions.query is not supported for safari. is there any other way to check if microphone permissions have been granted or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is old but hopefully this can help someone, heres what I did:

```js
// Check if mediaDevices loaded.
if(navigator.mediaDevices != undefined) {
  //Req microphone permissions
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function(stream) {
    // Mic permissions granted, handle however you wish
  }).catch(function(err) {
     // Mic permissions denied, handle however you wish
   })
} else {
  // Out of luck at this point, handle however you wish.
}
```

The explanation from the docs:

> It returns a Promise that resolves to a MediaStream object. If the
>   user denies permission, or matching media is not available, then the
>   promise is rejected with NotAllowedError or NotFoundError
>   respectively.

The caveat to this is the following:

> If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices
>   will be undefined, and you cannot use getUserMedia().

[Please see here for further information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)